Where does MongoDB calls run in Node.js?
I understand that I/O operations run in the libuv thread pool, but does Mongoose also operate within the thread pool?
Could someone clarify whether MongoDB operations through Mongoose also run in the libuv thread pool, or do they follow a different execution path?
